# jQueryUIのdatepickerを使いつつ元号の文字を入力したい

Tags: jquery-ui

jQueryUIのDatePickerウィジェットを適用しているテキストボックスがあるのですが、そこに元号を入力できるようにしたいです。
具体的には、下記のフォーマットでの文字入力を許可したいです。
「H26/4/1」
「h26/4/1」
「平成26/4/1」

しかし、テキストボックス(input[type=text])にdatepickerを使用すると、数字は入力できますが、Hなどの元号記号が入力できなくなります。
この入力制限を取り払うことができれば、一番良いのですが、それは可能でしょうか？
それさえできれば、あとはテキストボックスのchangeなりblurなりのイベントで、西暦のフォーマットに変換をかけてしまおうと思っているのですが・・・

なお、元号をカレンダーウィジェット上で選択できるよう改造したものは見つけましたが、要件は選択ではなく、文字入力です。

Comment: 日本語文字は入力できるとのことなので、訂正しました。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firefox、IEとも`datepicker()`後も日本語入力できましたが･･･
年を置き換えるのはこうすればできます。

アルファベットの入力を可能にするには`constrainInput: false`を設定します。

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var format = 2;
    $("input").datepicker({
        constrainInput: false,
        dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
        onSelect: function(e){
            var dateStr = $(this).val();
            var year = parseInt(dateStr.substr(2, 2), 10) + 12;
            var headStr = "";
            switch(format){
            case 0: headStr = "H";    break;
            case 1: headStr = "h";    break;
            case 2: headStr = "平成"; break;
            }
            $(this).val(dateStr.replace(/^[0-9]{4}/, headStr+year));
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

日付：<input type="text" />
```

Comment: すみません、確認不足でした。確かに日本語は入力できますね。ただ、Hとかは入力できないです。

Comment: @mok2pok さん アルファベット入力に対応しました。

Comment: ありがとうございます！うまくできました。